# In Python, what's the best way to get the closest integers for two dimensions?

Tags: python

I have a list of 2 dimensional tuples, unsorted, and of `n` size. I want to find which tuple has the closest dimensions to X and Y. What's the best way to do this?

```
target = (75, 75)
values = [
    (38, 61),
    (96, 36),
    (36, 40),
    (99, 83),
    (74, 76),
]
```

Using the `target` and `values`, the method should produce the answer `(74, 76)`.

**Edit**

The [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12697090/28360) lead me to this exact method, for anyone who lands here:

```
def distance(item, target):
    return ((item[0] - target[0]) ** 2 + (item[1] - target[1]) ** 2) ** 0.5

best = min(values, key=lambda x: distance(x, target))
```

This is a [Cartesian Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system#Distance_between_two_points) problem.

1. First take the square of the test value's `x` minus the optimal `x` value.
2. Then take the square of the test value's `y` minus the optimal `y` value.
3. Finally take the square root of step 1 plus step 2, which gives you the distance.
4. Apply this to all items in the list, and the lowest number (using the `min` function) will give you the best fit.

Comment: [Cartesian distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system#Distance_between_two_points), [`min()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#min)

Comment: This question is unanswerable unless you define what you mean by "dimension" and what it means for a "dimension to be close"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def distance(tup1,tup2):
    """
        This question is unanswerable unless you can specify this

        examples for 2d (you can write more general N-dimensional code if you need):
        cartesian: math.sqrt((tup2[0]-tup1[0])**2 + (tup2[1]-tup1[1])**2)
        manhattan: (tup2[0]-tup1[0]) + (tup2[1]-tup1[1])
    """
    return # YOUR CODE HERE

min(values, key=lambda x:distance(target,x))
```

Comment: Oooh, using a lambda here, that's what I was missing.  +1.

Comment: Thanks, you're correct in assuming that the list elements will always be 2-dimensional. I'll update my question to have the final code, but this is the answer. Thanks again.

Comment: @sberry: Oops sorry, I should have edited your answer rather than replying. For the record, one could also define a curried function, `def distanceToTarget(x): return distance(target,x)` (or use `functools.partial`, which is kind of poorly implemented). If `target` was a global variable, one could declare it as `global target` in the keyfunc.

Comment: In the 2d case, there's also `math.hypot`.  If you're just finding the minimum, you don't need to take the square root (the value which minimizes d^2 will also minimize d).  Those are just tweaks, though, and Python's overhead is significant enough that whenever I guess what'll be fastest without timing I guess wrong..

Answer (score 1):

Just another perspective to the problem. As this is a problem of Cartesian plain, convert it to a complex plain and solve

```
>>> min((abs(complex(*e)-complex(*target)),e) for e in values)[-1]
(74, 76)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
closest = min([(abs(val[0]-target[0])+abs(val[1]-target[1]),val) for val in values])[1]
```

Is one way.